# ASP.NET Core 3 Dependency Injection - Data Access / Business Layer Class Library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Very new to DI and concepts so I'm struggling to find a solution to the following:

We have a Web Project (MVC, Core 3) and a Class Library (for all the business and data layers). We are trying to have a DBContext Class in the Class Library to handle all the DB connections (using connection string). We can DI into this DBContext the IConfiguration so we can extract the connection string from this and place into a local readonly string. We have a method to return the SQL Connection using this connection string.

The issue is when we are in a business class, we need to access the DBContext class to obtain a SQL Connection object. We cannot create a "new" DBContext as we do not have the IConfigration in the other business classes.

DBContext class library:

```
public class DBContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DBContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
    }

    public SqlConnection Connection()
    {
        return new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

So the problem lies when we look at the Customer class in the Class Library:

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer
{

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }


    public Customer(int customerId)
    {
        //load customer from the db from the id

        using (IDbConnection db = new DBContext().Connection())
        {
            //call SQL Stored Procedure here ....
        }

    }

}
```

We are unable to create a "new" DBContext to access the connection, as in the Customer Class we don't have the IConfiguration object to pass to the constructor.

How do we achieve this the "correct" way?

Is it as bad as having to DI the IConfiguration object into every single class library constructor e.g. Customer from all the web controllers, so we can pass it over to the DBContext? As this seems long winded.

Sorry if this is very basic DI stuff but just struggling to find a good example on how to do this stuff.

Thanks in advance,

Ro

Comment: If your Customer class works with the database itself, then dependencies must be injected into it to work with the database. Note: it can be just a connection string, instead of a IConfiguration.

Comment: In general, to comply with the SOLID principles, the Customer class must only perform business logic. A repository class should work with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }


    public Customer(ApplicationDbContext context, int customerId)
    {
        _context = context; //use _context to reference the db context.
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

And in Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices()  method:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevDb")));
```

Edit for Dapper:

In appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  
    "DefaultConnection": "<connection string here>"  
  }
```

Then add a class called ConnectionString in the solution. We will use this class to hold the connection string value from the configuration file and use it in our classes via dependency injection.

```
public sealed class ConnectionString  
{  
    public ConnectionString(string value) => Value = value;  
  
    public string Value { get; }  
}
```

Then Register the configuration in the ASP.NET Core dependency injection container in Startup.cs

```
var connectionString = new ConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));  
services.AddSingleton(connectionString);
```

Then add your repository class:

```
using Dapper;  
  
public class MovieRepository
{  
    private readonly ConnectionString _connectionString;  
  
    public MovieRepository(ConnectionString connectionString)  
    {  
        _connectionString = connectionString;  
    }  
  
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MovieModel>> GetAllMovies()  
    {  
        const string query = @"SELECT m.Id, m.Name,d.Name AS DirectorName, m.ReleaseYear  
                                FROM Movies m  
                                INNER JOIN Directors d  
                                ON m.DirectorId = d.Id";  
  
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))  
        {  
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<MovieModel>(query);  
            return result;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Then Register the Repository class in you DI container. Add the following code to ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddScoped<MovieRepository>();
```

Add the controller class MoviesController.cs and write an action method to fetch all movies using this MovieRepository.

```
[ApiController]  
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase  
{  
    private readonly MovieRepository _movieRepository;  
  
    public MoviesController(MovieRepository movieRepository)  
    {  
        _movieRepository = movieRepository;  
    }  
  
    [HttpGet("api/movies")]  
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovies()  
    {  
        return Ok(await _movieRepository.GetAllMovies());  
    }  
}
```

In this example, your ApplicationDbContext is equivalent to the movie repository. Answer from: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-dapper-for-data-access-in-asp-net-core-applications/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. In startup.cs I don't have service.AddDbContext. Just to mention I'm not using Entity Framework. Using Dapper in the DAL for all DB calls if this makes any difference?

Comment: Thank you Kevin. After a couple of reads I think this makes sense. It's quite different from how we are used to doing things. So there will be a separate repository per "type" e.g. customer, Product, Supplier and these each take a connectionString in the constructor,. These are wired into the Web proj via the startup.cs using the DI and each controller is then fed their repository in their constructor (DI). Then we call that repository methods for that type e.g. CustomerController has injected the CustomerRepository and then calls the CustomerRepository methods e.g. Get, Create, List etc